# Query runs in background increases CPU Usage

Tags: c#, linq, cpu-usage

I have a function that runs for every few seconds.

```
private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Task.Run(() => UpdateData());
}

private void UpdateData()
{ 
  //i have some other functions here 
  updateCache(list1, cachelist);
}


private void updateCache(List<T> searchResults, List<T> cacheList)
{
   var result = searchResults.Where(x => !cacheList.Any(y => x.Number == y.Number && x.FileName == y.FileName));
   cacheList.AddRange(result);
}
```

linq query in updateCache() function is trying to compare two lists and updates list1 if some new value is found in cachelist. This linq query is increasing CPU Usage very high and as this function runs every few seconds as long as the window is open the CPU usage is very high. How can I make this better?

Comment: You are looping over the searchResults over and over - is there no way you can handle the item added event of the collection instead? Each time more values go into searchResults the processing time is going to increase, it also depends on whether the objects that are occupying the list correctly implement `GetHashCode`

Comment: Why caching if you run the function every few seconds?

Comment: How fast is this?  Is the first instance completing before the next begins?
  Could it be that you are actually running this same query multiple times at any given point in time?  Also, Jeroen Heier makes a very good point

Comment: @JeroenHeier maybe my naming convention is bad :). When it comes to actual requirement then this makes sense. I explained a complex scenario in the most simplest way here. But I hope my question is clear.

Comment: @user7396598 Yes it completes before next begins. It takes atmost 4.5 seconds for each loop. I run this function for evry 10 seconds.

Comment: I strongly suggest your approach is **not safe** - regardless of speed. The fact you are running `updateCache` in a `Task` and its two `List<T>` parameters are being altered elsewhere means this code is unsafe. `List<T>` is not thread-safe and designed to work in that scenario. Switching it to a `Dictionary<T>` won't solve that. You need to use types that are intrinsically thread-safe (e.g. `ConcurrentDictionary<T>`).

Comment: See my answer for a thread safe implementation. I originally suggested ConcurrentDictionary but I think it would probably be more performant to just prevent update reentry.

Comment: @YuliBonner Your code may stop more than one update at once. But it doesn't stop reads and writes occurring at the same time - which is equally as unsafe.

Comment: @mjwills I read up a little bit on thread safety for dictionaries and it's converted me. I've changed my solution back to using ConcurrentDictionary. I've left the reentry block because I'm convinced that the unregulated amount of threads is as much, if not more, of the OP's performance problem than the efficiency of the updateCache method.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `cacheList` a `HashSet` or `Dictionary` so you don't have to loop over it anymore.

The other option would be to make searchResults a different type, and give it an event when an item is added, then subscribe to that event to add the item in cacheList. But this would really depend on whether your architecture allows for it.

Comment: You would also require a custom `IComparer`.

Comment: @NetMage na, I'd just go with a `Dictionary` and the key would be a `Tuple` of the Number and `FileName`

Comment: Okay, you would need a custom `IComparer` to use `HashSet` :)

Comment: @NetMage couldn't you just implement the Equal and GetHashCode to only look at those two properties? Obviously only if it makes sense that two objects are equal if those two properties are equal.

Comment: Yes, if you are okay with that.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Can you give me sample code on how to use it. I'm a beginner with c# and just started my project. So need some help

Comment: @user9323954 which would you like to use, Dictionary or HashSet?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich I would like to use hashset

Comment: Neither Dictionary or HashSet can be safely used, since neither are thread-safe for the situation where a read and write occur at the same time. You'll need to use `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the solution provided below. Part of your performance problem is likely the unintentional/uncontrolled concurrency. If you want updateCache to run multiple times concurrently, you should introduce some code to control this (regulate the number of threads, etc). But you probably don't want and don't need that. The better solution is probably to prevent reentry into updateCache.

```
    object _updateLock = new object();
    bool _isUpdating = false;
    bool IsUpdating
    {
        get { return _isUpdating; }
        set
        {
            lock (_updateLock)
            {
                _isUpdating = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateData()
    {
        if (!IsUpdating)
        {
            IsUpdating = true;
            updateCache(list1, cachelist);
            IsUpdating = false;
        }          
    }


    ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<int, string>, T> cache = new
          ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<int, string>, T>();

    public void updateCache()
    {

        foreach (var sr in searchResults)
        {
            var key = new Tuple<int, string>(sr.Number, sr.FileName);
            cache[key] = sr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Given that `ContainsKey` has to do a lookup for `key`, wouldn't it be just as efficient to leave off the `if` and just assign to the cache?